# R: saving lm object with least amount of space while still maintaining functionality of the predict function

Tags: r, linear-regression, prediction

I have developed a linear regression model using `lm`.  My main purpose is to predict a prediction interval using the function `predict`.

As it stands right now, the `lm` object is too big for my taste.  As a result, I was wondering if there was any way to reduce the size of `lm` object but still be able to use the `predict` function.

Right now I have deleted `effects`, `fitted.values`, `residuals`, and `model` from the `lm` object while still maintaining functionality of the `predict` function.  Now the `lm` object takes 88 mb of space, but this is still too high.

Is there any other way to reduce the size of the object even further while still being able to use `predict`?

Comment: [This page](https://blogs.oracle.com/R/entry/is_the_size_of_your) discusses how to decrease the size of your model without losing the functionality of `predict`, but I don't have time to read through it all right now.